# File not found exception in Application_Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

Hi all i am new in asp.net mvc. Sometimes i have an exception in `Application_Error` and i write it to my log file:

```
Error in  global.asax
System.Web.HttpException: File does not exist.
   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestForNonMapPathBasedVirtualFile(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I trying debug but i not see file name? How to see witch file cannot be found ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you debug, can you see in the request that the request is for a resource like an image, js file or something like that?

i sometimes get this messages when i get a request for an image (maybe referenced in a css file) which does not exists.

Comment: thank you for response it was image file ) i forgot about Request

Answer (score 1):

Add following method in `Global.asax` file

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    Log.Error("An error occurred", ex);
    Log.Error("Requested url: ", Request.RawUrl);
}
```

`Request.RawUrl` Give exact url which give an Error.

Now in your log file you should see:

```
Requested url: /favicon.ico
```